# Is it possible to create a clickable region on a map that is created programmatically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have recreated the map from the 1985 game "Balance of Power" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_of_Power_(video_game)), [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/msdos_Balance_of_Power_1985)) using the original map data and JavaScript.

What I would like to know is if it is possible using just JavaScript, CSS, and HTML to make each country a clickable region. What I would like to happen is if I click anywhere within a country's border, the entire country would be highlighted, i.e. filled in black to indicate that it has been selected.

Note: I would like to limit myself to JavaScript, CSS, and HTML to keep this a simple as possible, if at all possible.

Here is what the map looks like after it has been created from the original data.
[image]

And here is what the map should look like after a single country has been selected (only one country can be selected at a time).
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with just JavaScript and HTML? JavaScript without any browser API can’t do much. If you include the browser API then JS, CSS and HTML is basically the whole spectrum the browser supports. And also a library like d3 is JavaScript. What about SVG which is part of html5?

Comment: It sounds like you want to take a look at building [an SVG clickable map](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=svg+map+clickable&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0).

Comment: use HTML + SVG + CSS + Javascript, as any browser natively support.

Comment: We deal with broken code to fix of which the question lacks, please post JavaScript, CSS, and HTML as a [mcve].

Comment: Aside from the SVG solution, there's also the [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but just how much detail/accuracy do you need? clip-path in CSS could provide what you want if each country can be outlined by a reasonable number of straight lines. Give it a go and if still stuck put your code into your question with a description of the problem.

Comment: leaflet https://leafletjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and doing some research I decided to create a custom SVG map using the original data. Here is my first attempt.

[image]

The original map, created on a HTML canvas using JavaScript, is on the left and underneath the two SVG images on the right.

The SVG version contains just three North American countries and uses some CSS to fill in an individual country as you cross over its border and hover over it. Note: The code hasn't been optimized, each country has its own individual data structures, and there are still some glitches as you cross over some country borders (I would like to make it so the country is highlighted when you click on it instead of just crossing its border, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet).

Here's the JS/CSS/HTML code to create the SVG map images above:

```js
const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; // variable for the namespace
const svg = document.querySelector("svg"); // targeting the svg itself

const usa_main = document.querySelector("g#usa_main"); // targeting the united states div
const usa_alaska = document.querySelector("g#usa_alaska"); 
const canada_main = document.querySelector("g#canada_main");
const canada_victoria = document.querySelector("g#canada_victoria");
const mexico_main = document.querySelector("g#mexico_main"); 

const stroke_default = "black";
const fill_default = "none";

var outline_united_states = "";
var outline_alaska = "";
var outline_canada = "";
var outline_victoria_island = "";
var outline_mexico = "";

// United States
outline_united_states=createOutline(60, 84, "3ES6ES6ES6ES6ES6ES6ES6ES3ESWSWS3EN2ESESESEES5WSSWSSWWSWSW3SESEENENE3NENENN4ESSWSWSE3SWSSEEN3ENENN6E3N9EENENEN3E3SWSSWSWWSWWSWSEES4WS3WSWWSSWSWS3WNNW5SW3NWSSWSSESSWSWS3WSSWWSSWWSWSWWSWSSW4SE7SWS3WNWNNENNWNNE4N2WN3WN6WSESSWNWWNWWS3WSWWS3WSWWSWSW4S2WNWNW4NW3N5W3NWNN5WN2WN2WN2WN6W4NWNW9NNE3NE2NENE2NE2NENE2NENE2NENENE2NE2NENE2N");
let united_states = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
united_states.setAttribute("points", outline_united_states);
united_states.setAttribute("stroke", stroke_default);
united_states.setAttribute("fill", fill_default);
//svg.appendChild(united_states); // append the new polygon to the svg
usa_main.appendChild(united_states); 

// Alaska
outline_alaska = createOutline(30, 56, "3EN3ENEN2ESE2NW3NEN6ES2ENEN2EN3WS2W2NE2N2EN5E2SENENENW3N2ES4EN3EN6ES2ENEN2ESES2ESES6E2SWSWS2WSWS2WSWS2WSWSWS2WSWSWS2WSWS2W5SE9S2W5NW2NW2NWN2WNWN2WN3WS2WS3WNEN2ENEN2WS2WS2WS9W2WS5W3N");
let alaska = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
alaska.setAttribute("points", outline_alaska);
alaska.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
alaska.setAttribute("fill", "none");
usa_alaska.appendChild(alaska);

// Canada
outline_canada = createOutline(86, 41, "2ESES2ENENEN2ES2EN3ENE2S2ES4ESES3ESE2S7EN3ESE2SES2ES2EN3EN2ENENESESE4N2ENENEN2ENEN3EN2ESESWSWSWSW2SWSW2SE2SWSES2ENENENENESE2SWS2W2S3WS2WNWS3WS2WNW2S2E2S3WN3WS2WS2WS2W2SWS2WS2WS3W7S3ESES2ESES3ESW2SW2SE2SES2E3NENE2NEN2EN2ENENE5NENEN2ENE3N3ES3ENESESES2E2SW2SW2SES2EN2E2NE2NE6SW3SE3S3ESES2E4SW2S5WS9W6WS2WS2WSWSWSENEN3EN3ES2E2SWSWS2W2SES2ESES3WSWS4WNEN2EN2WS2WSW2NE3N3WSWSWS9WWS5W2SWS5WNENENENEN2ENWNEN5W2NE3NWNWN4WS2WSWN3WN6WN6WN6WN6WN6WN6WN6WN4W6NE2NE2NENE2NEN2E9NW5N2ENEN2ENENEN2ENENEN2ENEN2ENEN2ENENEN");
let canada = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
canada.setAttribute("points", outline_canada);
canada.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
canada.setAttribute("fill", "none");
canada_main.appendChild(canada);

// Victoria Island
outline_victoria_island = createOutline(114, 43, "2ES3EN2W2NEN3ESES2ENEN2ESES2E2SES3ESWS4WN2W2SES2WNWNWNWN6WS3W3N");
let victoria_island = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
victoria_island.setAttribute("points", outline_victoria_island);
victoria_island.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
victoria_island.setAttribute("fill", "none");
canada_victoria.appendChild(victoria_island);

// Mexico
outline_mexico = createOutline(47, 124, "6ES2ES2ES2ES5E2SE3S5E3SE4SESESE4SW2SW3SE2SW2SES2ESESEN2ES2ENENE3NEN3ESEN3ESWSW3SW2SWS4W3S4WSWS2WN6WS2WNWNWN2WNWN2WNWNWNWNWNW3NENE3N2W6NW3NW5NW3NW5NWNW9S3SE3SE8S2W2NW4NW2NW2NWNW2N2E2NW3NE6N");
let mexico = document.createElementNS(svgns, "polygon");
mexico.setAttribute("points", outline_mexico);
mexico.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
mexico.setAttribute("fill", "none");
mexico_main.appendChild(mexico);

function createOutline(origin_x, origin_y, direction_string) {
    var points = "";
    var current_x = parseInt(origin_x);
    var current_y = parseInt(origin_y);
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= direction_string.length; i++) {
        points = points + current_x.toString() + "," + current_y.toString() + " ";
        

        k = direction_string.substr(i, 1).charCodeAt(0) - 49;
        l = i + 1;

        if (k < 0 || k > 8) {
            k = 1;
            l = i;
        }

        direction = direction_string[l];

        switch (direction) {
            case "N":
                current_y = current_y - k;
                break;
            case "S":
                current_y = current_y + k;
                break;
            case "E":
                current_x = current_x + k;
                break;
            case "W":
                current_x = current_x - k;
                break;
        }
    }
    //console.log(points);
    //console.log(points.length);  
    
    return points;
}
```

```css
svg {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

g polygon:hover {
    fill: #000000;
}
```

```html
<svg id="map" class="map" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="512" height="342" viewBox="0 0 512 342">
    <g id="usa_main" class="north_america" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
    <g id="usa_alaska" class="north_america" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
    <g id="canada_main" class="north_america" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
    <g id="canada_victoria" class="north_america" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" /> 
    <g id="mexico_main" class="north_america" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" />
</svg>
```